# Pivot table with dynamic columns with average? In SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, average

I have a SQL table/query that gives me these columns:

Date   TestName   TestValue

I want a report that gives me something like this:

Date     Test1   Test2   Test3

3/1/2011 25      22      19

4/1/2011 22      32      12

Average  23.5    27      15.5

I can get a matrix to spread the test types out... but I can only get a subtotal. How can I get an average?

Answer (score 0):

Click on the **Data** cell in the matrix and then Right-Click and change the field **Expression** to  **=Avg(Fields!TestValue.Value)**

I believe this is what you are looking for.

Comment: If I do that, I won't see the values and I'd see the average repeated for every date. I want the avg of all the test dates at the bottom where the subtotal would go, but the data cell to have the actual data.

Comment: Sorry I can't accept the answer, since it really doesn't fix my problem.